# How can bind list to GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, binding

I have a list in a class and I want to use of this list in the other class and bind it into the gridview.

In this class I make my list :

```
namespace sample_table
{
public class ClassDal
{
    public List<phone> GetAll()
    {
        using (PracticeDBEntities1 context = new PracticeDBEntities1())
        {
            return context.phone.ToList();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and in this class I want to use it:

```
namespace sample_table
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassDal obj = new ClassDal();
        obj.GetAll();

        GridView1.DataSource = obj;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

but I receive this exception:

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind with list currently you are binding GridView with `ClassDAL` which is obviously not a List, you method `GetAll()` returns a List so you need to set **DataSource** that:

```
ClassDal obj = new ClassDal();
GridView1.DataSource = obj.GetAll();
```

or:

```
ClassDal obj = new ClassDal();
List<phone> list = obj.GetAll();
GridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: tnx,i tried it but i receive this exception on line gridviw1.databind();A field or property with the name 'obj' was not found on the selected data source.

Comment: what exception you got?

Comment: A field or property with the name 'obj' was not found on the selected data source.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ToList() extension method to convert the query to a list of items.

```
ClassDal obj = new ClassDal();
List<phone> list = obj.GetAll();
GridView1.DataSource = list.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks,I tried it but i received this exception:A field or property with the name 'obj' was not found on the selected data source.

Comment: @user3721173, Please post your grid view html part